# Simplify $\sqrt[x]{(-1)^{x+1}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In one of my math books that I have for a class I was asked to:

Simplify $$\sqrt[x]{(-1)^{x+1}}$$

I started off by writing it as a power:
$$((-1)^{x+1})^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
$$(-1)^{1+\frac{1}{x}}$$
$$(-1)^1\times(-1)^\frac{1}{x}$$
$$-1\sqrt[x]{(-1)}$$
Now, if I am not wrong, this can have two solutions. It is either real, if x is odd, and the answer would then be 1. If x is even, however, this would yeild a non-real result. But my book says otherwise. It says the answer should be $(-1)$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Looks more like the book made a mistake. But how did the book define $a^b$?

Comment: In the book, they define $a^m$ to be equal to $(a_{1} \cdot a_{2} \cdot ... \cdot a_{m})$. Why?

Comment: So it's only defined for natural exponents apparently. How is $\sqrt[x]{y}$ defined? (We need to be able to make sense of $\sqrt[x]{(-1)^{x+1}}$ before we can attempt to determine its value.)

Comment: @DanielFischer It's defined as $y^\frac{1}{x}$. The book also defines negative exponents as: $a^{-m} = \frac{1}{a^m}$ But my class is not really related to complex numbers, just real numbers.

Comment: But how is $y^{\frac{1}{x}}$ defined? What you wrote in the first comment doesn't make sense unless the exponent is a natural number.

Comment: Also, powers of negative numbers with real exponent are not usually defined in the context of real number

Comment: @DanielFischer It isn't really defines as anything, as far as I can tell. They just introduce the concept of exponents and roots "equalling out", such as $a^\frac{1}{x} \cdot a^x = a^1$

Comment: @enzotib Oh ok, that doesn't really seem to be in line with the Swedish education system. We've always been taught this rule?

Comment: In that case, the most you can do is to rewrite it as $$(-1)^{1 + \frac{1}{x}}\,.$$ What $(-1)^{1/x}$ should mean remains the author's secret.

Comment: @DanielFischer but wouldn't $(-1)^{1/x} = \sqrt[x]{-1}$? And btw, am I also correct in assuming there can't be a single real solution, but that when x is odd it will be complex?

Comment: Well, we could write it as $\sqrt[x]{-1}$. But *what does that mean*? Apparently the book doesn't provide a definition. By conventional interpretations of the notation, there are various options.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, I see. It doesn't really matter then? I can't really simplify it any further. But there is definitely not one real solution then, so -1 is wrong? :)

Comment: There are some values for which $-1$ is **a** correct answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, thank you. But obviously you cannot write $-1$ as a simplification of the original expression.